# Flutter Riverpod 2 ref.invalidate() doesn't work as expected

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have the following scenario. I have a Notifier which previously used autoDispose, but there is a case where I first need to read the Notifier, before watching / listening.
I thought the solve was simple, don't autoDispose, but manually invalidate when the widget unmounts. However when I invalidate - though onDispose is called - the provider is not recreated next time it is accessed. Am I misundering invalidate? Is this a bug?

Comment: ref.invalidate immediately rebuilds if there are any active watchers.

Comment: So if there are no watchers, it'll never rebuild?

Comment: Yes, the provider only rebuilds if it is listener or read.

Comment: The provider doesn't rebuild after the invalidate when I listen or read later. The scenario is when I'm not using autoDispose, and I want to close a project, I invalidate, then when the project resumes, I want to read again, which I'd expect the provider to rebuild, but it doesn't, it access the old, already disposed provider

Answer (score -1):

If the provider does'nt have a watcher or listener in this widget or its descendants it's better to use `ref.read` or `ref.read` instead of `ref.invalidate`

more information about ```read`` function here

https://docs-v2.riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading